# Elastic Beanstalk with docker-compose (nginx-container and static html): Simplest app not working; nginx-config partly ignored

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-config

I'm trying to deploy a very simple docker-application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk running with Amazon Linux 2 which supports docker-compose.yml files.

The app should just display an index.html-file.

Whether I upload a ZIP-file or deploy in AWS CodePipeline via CodeCommit - the result is the same:

**404 Not Found**

Connecting to the instance and inspecting the container-log via `docker logs nginx` I get the following output:

```
[error] 30#30: *4 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory)
```

Why is nginx looking inside **/etc/nginx/html** for index.html, when I provided a root-directive inside the server-block of `default.conf` (see below). Why is this directive being ignored?

Whenever I insert the root-directive into nginx.conf, restart nginx-service and restart nginx-container it works, but this is not an acceptable solution for several reasons.

### The following **does** work:

✓ nginx-container is created and active

✓ My custom default.conf file is in use since the `/health-check`-route is working.

### The following **does not** work:

x Elastic-Beanstalk is not creating a (shared) volume from the provided `hermeneus`-folder that nginx should point to.

## Folder-structure of my app

- hermeneus/

  - index.html
- nginx/

  - conf/

    - default.conf
  - nginx.dockerfile
- docker-compose.yml

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./nginx/nginx.dockerfile
      args:
        - NGINXUSER=${NGINXUSER:-www-data}
        - NGINXGROUP=${NGINXGROUP:-www-data}
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      # For ELB-healthchecks
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./hermeneus:/var/www/html
```

## nginx.dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.21.5
ARG NGINXGROUP
ARG NGINXUSER
ENV NGINXGROUP=${NGINXGROUP}
ENV NGINXUSER=${NGINXUSER}
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nano
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN sed -i "s/user www-data/user ${NGINXUSER}/g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD nginx/conf/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

RUN adduser -g ${NGINXGROUP} -s /bin/sh -D ${NGINXUSER}; exit 0
```

## default.conf (custom-nginx-config)

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    location /health-check {
        return 200;  
    }

}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
 
    index index.php index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

## Elastic Beanstalk-Settings that might be relevant

- Platform: Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.10
- Proxy-Server: none
- 1 Instance with Application Load Balancer
- Health-Check on Port 8080 to route /health-check which is successful

I hope you can help me out somehow, I'm really struggling.